# I Want to display images instead of text in multiselect attribute

Tags: image, multiselect

Hi I am new to magento and I am trying to display images instead of text using a multiselect attribute in the product page.

To be more specific I have created a multiselect attribute with 4 options such as **Precious**, **Made with love**, **Hand Crafted** and **One of its kind**.

The text of which ever option the site admin selects in the backend shows in the frontend of the product page. But I want to show images instead of the text in the frontend. Some thing like the image below.

[image]

Is there a way I could achieve it?

I am using magento 1.9 CE

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need an extension to do that, somethink like [Magento Color Swatches Pro](https://amasty.com/color-swatches-pro.html).

Since 1.9.1 there's a built-in configurable color swatches functionality to Magento, but that has its own downsides (You'd have to upload them over and over again for each single product). See [the official documentation](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable-swatch.html) for further info.

Comment: Hey Rob thank you for the suggestion its much appreciated. I surely will look at this extension and the documentation. However, is there a trick or a solution to do it programmatically??

Comment: It's a pretty complex work. You have to hook into attribute administration to upload images and connect them to the corresponding entries and you'd have to manipulate the configurable logic.